# Angular 2+ detect closing window

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, window-object

i have troubles detecting a closing window **after** the build is done.

```
const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', options);
newWindow.onbeforeunload = () => null;
newWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', (evt: BeforeUnloadEvent) => 
  {
    console.log(evt)
  }
);
```

it works great until i do the build, there the beforeunload event does not get triggered. i also tried placing a host listener in the new window's component:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
beforeUnloadHander(event: BeforeUnloadEvent): void {
  debugger;
}
```

but the same problem here. after the build is done, we don't arrive at the debugger anymore

anybody any idea what i am doing wrong? thanks for your help!

**Edit Workaround**

```
const heartBeatNewWindow = setInterval(() => {
  if (newWindow.closed) {
    this.canvasSettings.displayInNewWindow = false;
    clearTimeout(heartBeatNewWindow);
  }
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Try returning `false` in `beforeUnloadHander`

Comment: @trichetriche unfortunately the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar and my approach was the following:
I created a generic catch from close event windows in the constructor of my service, them call method what handle this event. Inside this method I validate the origin of this event is the correct to execute the logic I needed. Look this example:

Inside the constructor:

```
  if(window.addEventListener){
     window.addEventListener("message", this.authService.handleMessage.bind(this), false);
  }else{
     (<any>window).attachEvent('onmessage', this.authService.handleMessage.bind(this));
}
```

And my method to handle that event:

```
handleMessage(event: Event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const message = event as MessageEvent;

        // Only trust messages from the below origin.
        //
        if ((message.origin !== environment.BASE_URL)) return;

      const result = JSON.parse(message.data);

//Add your logic here
```

I Hope be helpfull.